# Does someone know how to implement Jquery Datatables in a Django framework?

Tags: django, datatables

I am trying to create a datatable using Datatables and Django, however I am lost. The most I get my web page to display is the json data. Below are my models:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


class LikeDefectMatrix(models.Model):
    area = models.TextField(db_column='AREA', blank=True, null=False, primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    type = models.TextField(db_column='TYPE', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    defect_name = models.TextField(db_column='DEFECT_NAME', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    update = models.TextField(db_column='UPDATE', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    code = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='CODE', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Like_Defect_Matrix'
```

Here are my views:

```
from .models import LikeDefectMatrix
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core import serializers

# Create your views here.


    def postsjson(request):
        object_list = LikeDefectMatrix.objects.all()
        json = serializers.serialize('json', object_list)
        return HttpResponse(json, content_type='application/json')
```

this is my base.html file:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        Example
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/jquery.dataTables.min.css'%}" />
        <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.dataTables.min.js' %}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock body %}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
{% block js %}
{% endblock js %}
</html>
```

and finally my datatables.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
        <div class="container">
            <table id="postsTable" class="table">
                 <thead>
                     <tr>
                         <th>area</th>
                         <th>type</th>
                         <th>defect_name</th>
                         <th>code</th>
                         <th>update</th>
                     </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
{% endblock body %}
{% block js %}
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#postsTable').DataTable( {
             "processing": true,
             "ajax": {
                 "processing": true,
                 "url": "{% url 'my_ajax_url' %}",
                 "dataSrc": ""
             },

             "columns": [
                     { "data": "area" },
                     { "data": "type" },
                     { "data": "defect_name"},
                     { "data": "update" },
                     { "data": "code" }
                 ]
         } );
     } );
 </script>
{% endblock js %}
```

I have been looking all over for a straight forward way of doing this but I have not been successful. I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: better to call ajax and get your table ready and than call datatable function  and your table should be in proper format that is <table> <thead><tr><th>..</thead><tbody><tr><td>..</tbody></table>

Comment: I finally figured out how to do it if anyone else looks at this here is the link to the tutorial. https://www.uno-de-piera.com/datatables-en-django/ . The link is in Spanish but the basics are the same as any other website